# Excel is showing 'Office File Validation' when created using POI in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-poi

I created a Microsoft Excel file with some data, colors, filters in it using apache POI in java. When ever i open that excel file, a security dialog is coming up with the message 'Security Alert - Office file validation'. Is there any way to suppress this alert? I want to do something in java code to not to display this alert.

**Below is the Alert box:**

[image]

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using? Did you try upgrading to the latest version if you're not on it? If you open the file in Excel and save it again, how do the POI generated and Excel re-saved files differ?

Comment: See if this helps - http://superuser.com/questions/375345/how-to-disable-irritating-office-file-validation-security-alert

Comment: I am using poi-3.7, Thanks for the link, but i am wondering if there is any way to handle this while creating the file in java code. Because i cannot ask my customers to turn off the security stuff.